# How to dynamically call this jquery function by passing different <id> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic, parameters

I have the following codes need to be manipulated:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example1').DataTable( {
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
} );
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table,{
    leftColumns:2 } ); } );
```

And I have 30+ id tags, such as #example2, #example3, #example4  need to be passed into

```
            var table = $('#example1').DataTable(
```

I am pretty sure there should be a way that I can dynamically alter this field instead of copying and pasting this function 30+ times....but I am new to jQuery/JavaScript and not so sure exactly how I can do this...Any input is greatly appreciated!

Edited:

I have also tried the following codes but it doesn't work:

```
     var obj = { #example1, #example2, #example3, #example4, #example5 };
            jQuery.each( obj, function(id) {
            var table = $(id).DataTable( {
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
} );
 new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table,{
    leftColumns:2}  );});
```

Edited Again:
Resolved using a simple array....

```
           $(document).ready(function() {

            var myArray = ["#example1", "#example2"];
            var i = 0
            for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
            id = myArray[i];
            var table = $(id).DataTable( {
                scrollY:        "300px",
               scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false
} );
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table,{
    leftColumns:2}  );}});
```

Comment: Give them a common class and use that instead of IDs?

Comment: Tried, the library doesn't seem to function if I use a common class.

Comment: try var obj= "example1"; $("#"+obj).DataTable({ // } );

Comment: Resolved using an array....